# How should i improve my jQuery click funciton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i'm learning some jQuery at the moment and got somewhat stuck with this .click function. I'm trying to "turn a light on and off", so to speak.
I am able to do so, but only once. Why is that, that my code only runs for one click event per item, and how should i improve it?

Link to my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6f7u/1/).

HTML

```
<div class="lightOn"></div>
<div class="lightOff"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.lightOn').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('lightOn');
    $(this).addClass('lightOff');
});
$('.lightOff').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('lightOff');
    $(this).addClass('lightOn');
});
```

CSS

```
.lightOn {
    height: 90px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:yellow;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
.lightOff {
    height: 90px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:grey;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: you can use `toggleClass` instead.

Comment: You could also use inheritance in your css to remove the tiny amount of duplicate code.  I.e. have a light class and a light.on and a light.off perhaps.

Comment: The only difference between your `lightOn` and `lightOff` class is the background color. You may consider creating an extra class for everything except the background-color.

Comment: _“Why is that, that my code only runs for one click event per item”_ – it doesn’t, it runs for every click. But you always do the same on every click – you remove the class `lightOn`, and set `lightOff` (for the first button, vice versa for the second). Your error is in assuming that `$('.lightOn').click()` would select the buttons dynamically based on the class they have each time – but it doesn’t, it only binds the event _once_ to the buttons. See the jQuery docs on `.on` for how to fix that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because you are removing the class you are selecting by, so for successive clicks the element no longer exists. Instead have a common `class` which remains, but add one to it to light up the object. Try this:

```
<div class="light"></div>
<div class="light"></div>
```

```css
.light.on {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.light {
    height: 90px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:grey;
    border-radius: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```js
$('.light').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/C6f7u/4/)

This method has the benefit of being able to handle `x` number of `.light` elements wihtout having to amend the jQuery selector you use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this might be the best one, since you will have less redundant CSS code. Thank you for this one!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you bind the functions to elements, not to selectors. That is to say, you bind a function that removes the class `lightOn` to the element that had that class originally. That function only ever removes the `lightOn` class and adds the `lightOff` class, even if that has already been done once.

There are two ways to fix this. One is with `on` and event delegation, which allows you to do something akin to binding to a selector. It attaches the handler to a parent element, and makes use of the fact that all ancestor elements are notified of events that originated on their descendents. So the function might be bound to `document.body`, but only elements that originated on an element matching the `.lightOn` selector will trigger the handler:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.lightOn', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('lightOn').addClass('lightOff');
}).on('click', '.lightOff', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('lightOff').addClass('lightOn');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/C6f7u/5/

Better, however, is to make use of jQuery's `toggleClass` function, which removes classes if the element currently has them and adds them if it doesn't.

```
$('.lightOn,.lightOff').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('lightOn lightOff');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/C6f7u/2/

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and the explanation. Up for that, but i had to give the "answered question check" to Rory McCrossans contribution, which was simpler and made it possible to reduce the css code. Thank you tho!

Comment: @htmlNewbie You're right to: his answer is better! But I think this answer is still worthwhile, since it explains what's going on in a bit more detail `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
$('.lightOn, .lightOff').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('lightOn lightOff');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h7639/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using toogleClass of jquery
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to attach your events to the parent element. In your case this is even mandatory, because you are changing the classes, which are used during the event binding. So, your HTML:

```
<div class="ligths">
    <div class="lightOn"></div>
    <div class="lightOff"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".ligths").on("click", "div", function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.hasClass("lightOn")) {
        el.removeClass("lightOn").addClass("lightOff");
    } else {
        el.removeClass("lightOff").addClass("lightOn");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C6f7u/7/